Gradient-free optimization in Qiskit without using pre-defined classes
Basically I want to build a gradient-free optimizer that classifies a very simple dataset (e.g. the sklearn make_moons) using scipy.optimize (Nelder-Mead or Powell method or something similar).
I want to achieve this without using Qiskit's predefined classes, such as VQC, SamplerQNN and the likes of it, but only implementing the circuit in Qiskit and training it by passing the results to the optimizer "by hand".
I'm achieving somewhat okay-ish results, but they are way worse than the ones I can achieve using the VQC class.
I was investigating the class a bit and found that they are using a NN to compute the gradients of the circuit, and then pass them to the optimizer. This would mean that the Nelder-Mead method in Qiskit is no longer gradient-free?
Do you have any ideas on how to approach this issue and what other steps have to be taken, in order to achieve similar results as in the VQC class?
